# show that $\{2, 4 ,..., 2m\}$ is complete residue system $ \mod m$ if and only if $m$ is odd

Tags: number-theory

show that $\{2, 4,..., 2m\}$ is complete residue system $\mod m$ if and only if $m$ is odd.
I know $\{1, 2 ,..., m\}$ is a complete residue system and $(2,m) = 0$ but how do I proceed?

help please!

Comment: Well $2, 4, \dots, 2m$ has at most as many distinct residues as $1,2,\dots,m$. If there were just as many it would be complete.

Comment: HINT: You have listed even numbers. When you divide them with an even number $m$ what can be the remainders?  For $m$ odd multiply your set with $(m+1)/2$.